# SimpleXML to CSV with missing tags

Tags: php, xml, csv, simplexml, fputcsv

So I have an XML file that looks similar to this:

```
<container>
<example1>some text</example1>
<example2>some text</example2>
<example3>some text</example3>
<example4>some text</example4>
</container>
<container>
<example1>some text</example1>
<example2>some text</example2>
<example4>some text</example4>
</container>
```

Basically, if `example3` doesn't contain any information, the XML author decided to leave it out completely. The trouble is, when I am using my script to convert to CSV, this particular XML file doesn't convert to CSV properly due to the text in the second `example4` being displayed under the header of `example3` in the CSV file.

This is the PHP script I have to normally works with other XML files.

```
$file='input.xml';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
    $f = fopen('output.csv', 'w');

    // array to hold the field names
    $headers = array(); 
    // loop through the first set of fields to get names
    foreach ($xml->container->children() as $field) { 
        // put the field name into array
        $headers[] = $field->getName(); 
    }
    // print headers to CSV
    fputcsv($f, $headers, ',', '"');

    foreach ($xml->container as $information) {
        fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($information), ',', '"');
    }
    fclose($f);
}
```

I can't figure out how to predefine the headers that I need and insert the correct information in the correct columns in the CSV.

Any pointers much appreciated.

thanks

mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first entry always present all fields, then its enougth to iterate over the header fields for each line and look if the current line has all entrys.

```
foreach ($xml->container as $information) {
    $vars = get_object_vars($information);
    $line = array();
    foreach($headers as $field) {
        $line[] = isset($vars[$field]) ? $vars[$field] : '';
    }
    fputcsv($f, $line, ',', '"');
}
```